# Read the file when files is added to a folder and insert the content to a database

Tags: php

I want to listen in on the folder (see if there are any changes) and when any file is added I want to insert the content of that file to a table and delete the file afterwards.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Do you want to *listen in* on the folder and add the file to the database the instance it is added or do you want the user to manually upload the file on a website and then you add it to the servers harddrive and the database?

Comment: And what is the weird php tag in your question all about? And do you know what google is?

Comment: plz elaborate ,@jules

Comment: @Mathlight Yes, I use windows scheduler to run my script, it works just fine but what I wanted to do now is everytime that a file is added the script will run. In task scheduler the trigger is time. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Andresch serj: I want to listen in on the folder and when the file is added I will insert the content of the file to a table and delete the file afterwards. Thank your for your reply.

Comment: @codelover: Thank you for your reply. Please find my reply to Andresch

Comment: @Andresch Serj: What google? The php tag is just a workaround for the site to accept my naive question.

Comment: @jules maybe there is a reason you needed a workaround? your question is way too bold and you needed to elaborate in the comments. Anyhow, whtat flauntster wrote is almost what you want right? what is he/she missing?

Comment: @jules keep in mind, what you ask for is a feature. You may get answers leading you in the right direction, but nobody here will simply do all the work for you and give you your solution. That's not what this website is about. However, i think you'll be able to google your way along what flauntster wrote.

Answer (score 2):

1. create a db table to keep track of files in the folder
2. create a script that compares folder contents with that db table
3. if files found which aren't in the table, sanitize content and insert into db, and add filename to tracking table
4. if a file in table is no longer in folder, remove that file's content from db and remove from tracking table
5. set script to run via cron so that it checks folder at the interval you specify

hope this helps point you in the right direction :)

Comment: Thank you @flaunster, but this not what I intended to do.